# Receive array values in VBA from a callback function that passes an array from fortran

Tags: arrays, vba, dll, fortran

I am using excel/vba as a front end to access an optimization program written in fortran.  The fortran dll uses a callback routine to pass an array of doubles back to vba and to also obtain additional informtation.  I can succesfully do this for the first element in each array, but cannot figure out how to access the other elements.

The fortran call back is soemthing like

```
logical function vbfunction(x, f, c) bind(c)
    use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
    real*8,dimension(100),intent(inout) :: x, c
    real*8, intent(inout)               ::f
end function
```

the VBA is

```
Function callback(X As Double, ByRef f As Double, ByRef C As Double) As Boolean
```

Fortran is returning the address of the first element of each array so VBa can easily access this, but I need to access the other elements in vba.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. We need the actual code and not just "something like". In general, the array elements are in succession in memory so if you can work with the addresses, you should be able to access other elements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.